# Parameter pack expansion within parentheses gives bizarre output

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I am trying to implement a function which accepts a variable number of strings and forwards to a print function, which expects a `char` pointer and `size` for every string, interleaved.

Example:

```
std::string a = "123";
std::string b = "1234";
forward(a, b); // should call doPrint(a.c_str(), a.size(), b.c_str(), b.size())
```

I thought that the following should be a correct implementation, but even though it compiles the behavior is very surprising to me.

```
template <class ...Args>
void forward(const Args & ... args) {
  doPrint( (args.c_str(), args.size())...);
}
```

`forward(a, b)` calls `doPrint(3, 4)`, and not `doPrint("123", 3, "1234", 4)`, as if I had written `doPrint((args.size())...)`. The call to `c_str()` is ignored completely by the compiler.

I tried `g++`, `clang`, and `icc` with all yielding the same output. What is wrong with `(args.c_str(), args.size())...`?

Indeed, `std::make_tuple(args.c_str(), args.size())...` works as expected, but let's say I cannot change `doPrint` to accept and process tuples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The comma operator is an expression whose value is the value of the last expression.
For example:

```
    int a = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
    assert(a == 6);
```

What you can try instead is using tuples:

```
    doPrint(std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(argc.c_str(), args.size())...));
```

Then `doPrint` will need to be changed to work with a tuple; it could unpack the tuple back into a parameter pack if desired or just work with the tuple directly.

Example unpacking tuple:

```
    template <class Tuple, std::size_t ... indices>
    doPrint(Tuple t, std::integer_sequence<size_t, indices...>)
    {
        doPrint(std::get<indices>(t)...);
    }

    template <class Tuple>
    doPrint(Tuple t)
    {
        doPrint(t, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>());
    }
```

There could be some problems with ambiguous function names so you may need to change the names of these helper functions, but hopefully this is enough for you to get going.

Comment: Your solution works great, thanks! By using this wrapper I don't have to modify doPrint at all, only add new overloads. I think the three dots should be one parenthesis to the left, though: `doPrint(std::tuple_cat( ...))` instead of `doPrint(std::tuple_cat( )...)`, otherwise the top-level tuple is not produced and tuple_cat is more or less a NOP.

Comment: @GeorgiosBitzes you can write your own `make_index_sequence` and `integer_sequence`.

Comment: `int a = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6;` is not valid C++.

Comment: @T.C. Ah, you got me!  parentheses work though in this case.

Answer (score 5):

`(args.c_str(), args.size())` is a comma-separated expression, meaning that only the last part (`args.size()`) will be passed to the function.

It will then repeat this for each parameter, so it will actually call `doPrint` just with the strings sizes!

You should change `doPrint` to use tuples instead, otherwise you have to use some crazy template meta-programming stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably do it this way in order to avoid exposing tuples to the programming interface:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

extern void doPrint(...);

namespace detail {
  template<std::size_t...Is, class Tuple>
  void forward(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tuple&& tuple)
  {
    doPrint(std::get<Is>(tuple)...);
  }
}

template<class...Strings>
void forward(Strings&&... strings)
{
  detail::forward(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Strings) * 2>(),
          std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(strings.data(), strings.size())...)
          );
}

int main()
{
  std::string a = "123";
  std::string b = "1234";
  forward(a, b); // should call doPrint(a.c_str(), a.size(), b.c_str(), b.size())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jason Turner demonstrates a concise way to expand variadic templates using an initializer list in this video:

http://articles.emptycrate.com/2016/05/09/variadic_expansion_wrap_up.html

```
template< typename ... T >
void do_print(T ... args)
{
    (void)std::initializer_list<int> {
        (std::cout << args.c_str() << ": "
        << args.size() << "\n",     0)...
    };
}

template< typename ... T >
void forward_print(T ... args)
{
    do_print(args...);
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";

    std::string a = "1234";
    std::string b = "567";

    forward_print(a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

This works with g++ -std=c++11

Comment: Interesting technique, but I don't see how it can work when you are instead trying to pass the arguments to another function.

Comment: The idea is that you don't need to redirect/specialize using this technique. I've rewritten it to use a forwarding function but you could just call do_print directly.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, do_print receives a parameter pack of strings in this case, which is not desirable. doPrint expects to be called with `char*` and `size` interleaved, and it's a function inside an external library which I cannot alter.